# Use of '*' and '+' in Lua pattern

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

```
i, j = string.find("the number 1298 is even", "%d+")
print(i,j)
```

In above code, If I use `%d+`, I get `12,15` which is expected but with `%d*` , It returns `1,0`. The only difference between the two is that `*` accepts 0 value as well but `+` accepts 1 or more. But why is it returning `1,0`?

Comment: `%d*` matches an empty string before first symbol of your string.

Comment: Still not clear , explain, please?

Comment: `1` = position of the first symbol of empty string, `0` = position of the last symbol.  `length = (pos_last_symbol - pos_first_symbol + 1) = 0` as expected.

Comment: but how does it find empty string here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the pattern `%d+` matches one or more digits, and `%d*` matches zero or more digits, so in your example, `%d+` matches `"1298"`, while `%d*` matches an empty string in the beginning. Zero occurrence of digits can be matched by `%d*`, that's the difference between `+` and `*`.

Second, the index `1` and `0` for the empty string seems a bit odd, but it makes sense. Index `1` means the beginning of the string, but for the end index of the empty string, you can't have `1` because it would mean the match is the first character `"t"`, so it must be less than the beginning index, `0` is the one you got.

Furthermore, the return value of `string.find()` can be used as the arguments for [`string.sub()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.sub) to get the substring that is found. In the call `string.sub (s, i, j)`, if `i` is greater than `j`, it returns an empty string.

Comment: Thank you Yu hao, You solved my doubt about the indexes. But, I still can't make it out what exactly do you mean by empty string here? Why would %d* match an empty string when I have some digits in the string?

Comment: I got it I got it ! You mean that %d* would have matched if and only if I had digits in this string from very beginning. Right?